# oracle trigger count one table after insert update another

Tags: mysql, oracle, triggers, count, sql-update

I have this trigger in mysql which works fine:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_trainee AFTER INSERT ON trainee
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE training_activities SET NO_of_Trainees = 
( SELECT COUNT(SN)
FROM trainee
WHERE trainee.training_type = training_activities.SN
)
```

And I tried converting to oracle like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ins_trainee
AFTER INSERT ON trainee
FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN
UPDATE training_activities SET NO_of_Trainees =
SELECT COUNT(SN)
FROM trainee
WHERE trainee.training_type = training_activities.SN;

END;
/
```

But I get `warning: trigger created with compilation errors`

And `show errors` gives:

```
2/1     PL/SQL: SQL Statemnet Ignored
2/49    PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Comment: Try surrounding the select with parenthesis

Comment: it should be count(*) or count (training_type) instead of count(SN).